# How can I join these two queries?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Here's what I want to accomplish:
Select all rows from table "posts" while also fetching linked entities, such as the author (from table "users") and the names of the categories the post belongs to (from table "categories").

These are my two queries so far:
This one fetches the posts:

> `SELECT
>
>       posts.*
>
>       , users.authorName AS author
>
>       FROM posts
>
>       INNER JOIN users
>
>       ON users.id = posts.author`

And this one fetches a comma separated list of categories for a specific post:

> `SELECT
>
>                   GROUP_CONCAT(categories.category) AS categories
>
>                   FROM categories
>
>                   INNER JOIN post_category
>
>                       ON post_category.categoryID = categories.id
>
>                   WHERE
>
>                       post_category.postID = ?`

The two queries on their own work fine.

Naturally when the two are combined, I wouldn't need the WHERE clause of the second query. 
I tried using the second query as a sub-query within the first one's SELECT clause, but that fetched a comma separated list of ALL categories for ALL posts. I want only the categories for the post I'm currently iterating over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I apologize if any of this is unclear - it's hard enough for me to think about, let alone describe to other people ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.authorName AS author,
       GROUP_CONCAT(categories.category) AS categories
  FROM posts, users, categories, post_category
 WHERE users.id = posts.author
   AND post_category.categoryID = categories.id
   AND post_category.postID = posts.id
 GROUP BY posts.* /* list actual columns here */, author
```

Or did I miss something?

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!
It looks like I was over complicating it with the inner joins.

Comment: It may work, but I suspect you'll run into performance problems down the road.  A 4-way cross join is a bad idea.

Comment: I wasn't aware there are performance issues between the two types of joins. A quick google search though landed me on this page of the MySQL documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). It claims
>In MySQL, CROSS JOIN is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent.

So hopefully I won't encounter any performance hits b/c I'm using MySQL.

Comment: @Peter - performance problems down the road, while possible, would more likely be caused by GROUP BY rather than join (assuming, of course, that appropriate indexes have been set up). Query you've suggested in your answer will end up doing the very same cross join.

Answer (score 1):

I think your subquery approach should work fine, but you still need the where clause in your subquery.  How else would MySQL know which rows to retrieve?  Try:

```
SELECT posts.*, users.authorName AS author,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(categories.category) 
     FROM categories
     INNER JOIN post_category ON post_category.categoryID = categories.id
     WHERE post_category.postID = posts.postID) AS categories
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author
```